# Need some help inserting a text file into a text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to display a text file in a text widget and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
def viewfile():
    view = Tk()
    view.title('Text')
    view.geometry('700x700')
    text = Text(view)
    with open("scores.txt", 'r') as file:
        view.insert(INSERT, file.read())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a text widget with:

```
text = Text(view)
```

Now you need to pack it to show it on the widget:

```
text.pack()
```

Then you can insert the text with:

```
text.insert(END, file.read())
```

More examples can be found at [www.python-course.eu/tkinter_text_widget.php](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_text_widget.php)

Comment: Wow I just realized I forgot to pack it... Thanks so much !! :)

Comment: @Astrid No worries. If this answer helped you, make sure to give it a green tick.